# DataGridView sort by one main column but order so that those with a specific value in another column are grouped together

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm trying to implement a DataGridView to display some information.

I have two columns 'Time' (this is the time spent doing the current action) and 'Status' (which shows the current status of the user)

There are 3 statuses, 'Ready' 'Incall' and 'Pause'

I want all those with status 'Incall' to be at the bottom of the DataGridView, 'Ready' in the middle of the 3 and 'Pause' at the top. While still sorting by the highest value in the 'Time' column.

An example would be

Status       Time

```
PAUSE        104
PAUSE        99
PAUSE        12
READY        50
READY        12
READY        3
INCALL       900
INCALL       200
INCALL       3
INCALL       1
```

I've had a look at implementing `IComparer` using Microsofts documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.sort?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=windowsdesktop-7.0#System_Windows_Forms_DataGridView_Sort_System_Collections_IComparer_)

And it does what I want in terms of ordering by the Status, however some of the values are in the wrong order by 'Time' so I get for example:

```
PAUSE      50
PAUSE      43
READY      100
READY      50
READY      106
READY      190
INCALL     900
INCALL     760
INCALL     400
INCALL     765
```

Here's where I implement the `CustomComparer` which implements `IComparer`

```
private class CustomComparer : IComparer
{
    private static int sortModifier = -1;

    public CustomComparer(SortOrder sortOrder)
    {
        if(sortOrder == SortOrder.Descending)
        {
            sortModifier = -1;
        } else if (sortOrder == SortOrder.Ascending)
        {
            sortModifier = 1;
        }                    
    }

    public int Compare(object x, object y)
    {
        DataGridViewRow row1 = (DataGridViewRow)x;
        DataGridViewRow row2 = (DataGridViewRow)y;

        
        result = row1.Cells["Status"].Value.ToString().CompareTo(row2.Cells["Status"].Value.ToString());

        // If the the columns are the same sort based on Time
        if (result == 0)
        {
            result = System.String.Compare(row1.Cells["Time"].Value.ToString(), row2.Cells["Time"].Value.ToString());
        }
                
        // If the the columns are the same sort based on Time
        return result * sortModifier;
    }
}
```

And here's where I call it after populating the GridListView

```
monitor_DataGridView.Sort(new CustomComparer(SortOrder.Descending));
```

I think it must be due to the fact that the CustomComparer compares the first column, and if they are equal does not then compare the 'time' column afterwards which would explain why most are in order (could be coincidence)

Any help would be appreciated.
Best,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need to compare Time as integer instead of string:

```
    if (result == 0) {
        result = ((int)row1.Cells["Time"].Value).CompareTo(row2.Cells["Time"].Value));
    }
```

<--> if needed

Comment: Oh wow that's an oversight and a half